# Monitoring the performance of a system for testing purposes?

Tags: monitoring, testing

I have a system in which I test the releases of a software suit.  This system includes multiple Red Hat 5 servers and Windows clients on a closed internal network.  I need to monitor every aspect of the system for memory, network, and CPU usage.

Currently I use the **[nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/WikiPtype/nmon)** for monitoring the Red Hat servers and the built in Performance Monitor for Windows.  There must be some better tools than these that have report generation capabilities.

What tools does the community use for performance monitoring?

Comment: Check out http://serverfault.com/questions/1596/application-monitoring-tools, http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers, or even http://serverfault.com/questions/2644/monitor-analyze-report-resource-trends-on-a-single-server-perfmon for very similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying out [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net) and/or [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org), in conjunction with SNMP and the correct sets of MIB's you should be able to get what you want.  There are other solutions but most of them are commercial offerings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Xymon (hobbitmon)

Client runs on Unix & Windows, it monitors a lot of metrics out-of-the-box and you can add custom checks & metrics. It's easy to configure.

Homepage & demo : http://www.xymon.com/

Server/client rpms for RHEL5 : h**p://staff.telkomsa.net/packages/rhel5/xymon/i386/

Windows client : h**p://sourceforge.net/projects/bbwin

(Sorry for bad links but I can post only one as I'm a new user ^^)

Comment: We just upgraded from BBPE to xymon.  It's awesome.  BBWin even works on x64 clients if you are willing to do the registry fix.